# is this Workflow for texture atlas ok?

Tags: texturing, uv

I ve issues about texture atlas , I ve made 
my texture atlas in blender, I ve unwrap manual , then organize the UV manual and then export to unity.

in the firts pic everything seems allright, 
 I use Pack island,I think that  that is a problem, broken the scale or miss something (see the paint section) , I ve apply the scale of every object and then bring em to unity engine... I ve Loaded the meshes on Unity's heritage  and Texture to a folder.

The process in blender and (then paint :D to think the solution ??)

[image: workflow in Blender]

that is the problem 
[image: result in Unity]

Comment: If you move or resize your UV islands **after** you created the texture atlas, it's quite logical that it won't match the objects anymore.

Comment: I should scale all the uv coordiantes for all objects first? then press "finish texture atlas"  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem in Unity,

1. Go to the "Project" window, select one of the model (model of the texture atlas)
2. go to the "Inspector" window, click on the "Model" tab,
3. and check "Swap UVS"
4. Repeat the operation for each model of the texture atlas.

That's how I solve this problem. If you have another solution, don't hesitate to share it.

Answer (score 5):

The bullet-proof method of using the Texture Atlas add-on works (at least for me) as follows:

1. UV-unwrap and texture every object.
2. Select all the objects you want to create the Texture Atlas for.
3. Go to "Properties Panel - Render - Texture Atlas" and click the "+"-icon to create a new Texture Atlas.
   [image: create Texture Atlas]
4. Select a reasonable image resolution, select "No_Unwrap" and then "ManualUnwrap".
   [image: Start Unwrapping]
5. In the UV/Image Editor, go to "Menu - UV - Average Island Scale" (this provides uniform texture spaces for all the objects), then "Menu - UV - Pack Islands".
   [image: distribute UV islands]
6. Move around all UV islands, until satisfied.
7. Select "FinishManualUnwrap".
8. Bake the textures from every object individually to the new Texture Atlas.
   [image: Bake Object Textures]

Comment: The last step -> Number 8 , you said "Bake the textures from every object individually to the new Texture Atlas."  ...I should Bake (go to edit mode, select whole mesh, then go to "baking section" -> bake (chose texture) for diffuse color map.

Comment: Yep. A texture atlas is simply one texture for several objects/meshes. In Step 1 I mentioned that every object has its own UV map and texture. This method also works if you want to bake individual normal/specularity/AO maps onto a texture atlas. If you want, you can join the individual objects into one object with several submeshes, once you're done with the texture atlas.

Comment: I want to keep the original ones uv for every objects for the future purpose, AO, spec ( hitting the differents baking modes...) , also I want to have different objects ,  but for now I just want to create a diffuse map, texture paint and make the atlas texture. I should see the  step number 8 and make the same you ve made in the animation.

Comment: Then either work with a copy of the file or create copies of the objects. You still have the original UV maps despite using the Texture Atlas add-on. The only thing you have to check is if Unity can handle different UV maps in one object.

Comment: it is necessary to create a new material for all the objects who will share the atlas texture? I think I had created a new material for all of them and then I had painted on that material .                           http://imgur.com/a/pp2gB

Comment: Yes. And select TextureAtlas under UV map.