# Change Materials to Textures

Tags: uv-image-editor

I just started with blender and I found this model on blend swap https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/68978 and I need the materials as texture to use it in HitFilm Pro.

I tried to create the textures but I wasn't able to combine the UV maps.
Could someone do it for me or tell me how to do it?
would be very nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a node made material into an image texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is this Workflow for texture atlas ok?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66710/is-this-workflow-for-texture-atlas-ok)