# Colours underneath bleeding through when painting

Tags: texturing, uv

So very new to Blender.  I'm in the process of making a little cart for a roller coaster.

1. I unwrapped the seats and textured them and that was fine.
2. When attempting to texture the front of the coasters cab, it is revealing the colour grid I used underneath.
3. Can I use a separate image for each object? Or does the cushion and the coaster all need to be on one image?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your model consists of at least two separate meshes.

Right now, the front of the coaster uses the same texture as the seats, which means you have to create either a new material for it or you need to adjust the UV layout for both meshes so they don't overlap.

One possible solution to use one material (and one texture) for all the meshes in your model would be using a [Texture Atlas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66713/23985).

If you want to use two separate textures, you need to set up a separate material for each mesh.

Comment: Thank's for the answer.  I shall give that a go.

My other issue (I'm not sure if you can see it in that picture).  But the blue I am painting on the texture and over the colour grid, is mixing with the colour grid underneath.  And giving a strange affect.  

I've added another photo which shows it a bit clearer.

Comment: @OliverTommy - You need to put the strength slider all the way up to 1.

Comment: Gave it a go, but still yielding the same results.  Have added another pic.